# Export associative array to CSV including nulls and headers from each array

Tags: php

I am trying to export associative array / object to a CSV file. 
Below is the code sample i am using:

```
function array_keys_multi(array $array) {
    $uniquekeys = array();
    foreach ($array as $splitArray) {
        $keys = array_keys($splitArray);
        $uniquekeys = array_merge($keys, $uniquekeys);
    }
    return array_unique($uniquekeys);
}

function outputCsv($fileName, $Array)
{
    ob_clean();
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);    
    if(isset($Array)){
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $keys = array_keys_multi($Array);
        fputcsv($fp, $keys);
        $keys = array_flip($keys);
        foreach($Array AS $values){
            fputcsv($fp, array_merge($keys,$values));
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ob_flush();
}

$data = array(
    array('item' => 'Server', 'cost' => 10000, 'approved_by' => 'Joe'),
    array('item' => 'Mt Dew', 'cost' => 1.25, 'approved_by' => 'John'),
    array('item' => 'IntelliJ', 'cost' => 500, 'approved_by' => 'James', 'extra' => 'data1', 'extra1' => 'data2', 'extra3' => ''),
    array('item' => 'IDEA', 'cost' => 500, 'approved_by' => 'James', 'extra1' => 'data2', 'extra3' => 'data3')
);

outputCsv('expenses.csv', $data);
```

**Output**

```
item     cost   approved_by extra1  extra3  extra
Server   10000  Joe         3       4       8
Mt Dew   1.25   John        3       4       8
IntelliJ 500    James      data2            data1
IDEA     500    James      data2    data3   8
```

**Desired Output**

```
item     cost  approved_by extra extra1 extra3
Server   10000 Joe         null  null   null
MtDew    1.25  John        null  null   null
IntelliJ 500   James       data1 data2  null
IDEA     500   James       data2 null   data3
```

Can anyone please verify this code and let me know where is the mistake or needs to change?

Comment: You have to find all distinct keys in subarrays and use them.

Comment: @u_mulder i have edited the code. can you check whats missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do it

```
<?php
function array_keys_multi(array $array) {
    $uniquekeys = array();
    foreach ($array as $splitArray) {
        $keys = array_keys($splitArray);
        // instead of array_merge($keys, $uniquekeys) to obtain a header row
        // like: item, cost, approved_by, extra, extra1, extra3, etc.
        // it depends on the order of insertion in the original $array.
        $uniquekeys = array_merge($uniquekeys, $keys);
    }
    return array_unique($uniquekeys);
}

function outputCsv($fileName, $Array)
{
    ob_clean();
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);    
    if(isset($Array)){
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $keys = array_keys_multi($Array);
        fputcsv($fp, $keys);
        $keys = array_flip($keys);
        foreach($Array AS $values){
            // merge both keys and values, keeping in mind that some keys
            // that aren't originally in $values will have integer values
            // that simply represent their indexes...
            $fields = array_merge($keys, $values);
            // loop through the fields of csv line
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                // if the key isn't originally in $values
                if (!in_array($key, array_keys($values))) {
                    // make it null
                    $fields[$key] = null;
                }
            }
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ob_flush();
}
```

resulting in your desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks @yassine-addi.  This helped me.